# Git reverting back

Tags: git

`git log` says

```
commit 2bf345e15dadba9f2e01ef2e0c3890d6cbab1153
Merge: d3b6ba8 aa94bf7
Author: Stack Overflow User <user@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 14 01:00:48 2012 -0500

    Merge branch 'master' of bitbucket.org:hobbes3/scoutmob

commit d3b6ba8f1d57c530c2d8ab9bb879fcac67d3de35
Author: Stack Overflow User <user@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 14 00:59:37 2012 -0500

    Revert "Added image info window"

    This reverts commit fad04be93334647d1b1e3b4d454a70819213ecac.

commit d119c3961da515c0cb2c6c9154003e52846cf848
Author: Stack Overflow User <user@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 14 00:22:56 2012 -0500

    Revert "Moved some files around to combine the common folder between scoutmob and ajax-example"

    This reverts commit 845f8d52c3655f3cf6b03da057281e5fb303721c.

commit aa94bf75fb064c6fe521501765d86c894aa5b436
Author: Another user <user_two@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Sat Feb 11 10:42:03 2012 -0500

    removing .txt

commit b633d23a5b10ad7531855905d6f41897ce6726ad
Author: Another user <user_two@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Sat Feb 11 10:40:04 2012 -0500

    testing data import

commit fad04be93334647d1b1e3b4d454a70819213ecac
Author: Stack Overflow User <user@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Sat Feb 11 03:55:54 2012 -0500

    Added image info window

commit 51f9cc7cd19f15540ac2631168a0a91c03a30139
Author: Stack Overflow User <user@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 7 22:29:58 2012 -0500

    Added deal info to the info window of the marker.

....

commit 845f8d52c3655f3cf6b03da057281e5fb303721c
Author: Stack Overflow User <user@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Tue Jan 31 10:42:21 2012 -0500

    Moved some files around to combine the common folder between scoutmob and ajax-example
```

'git status' says

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

`git branch -rv` says

```
origin/HEAD    -> origin/master
origin/master  aa94bf7 removing .txt
origin/working cb65aef My location now works. Will work on the graphics next.
```

A couple of days ago my master branch was at the most current commit at `fad04be`. Then I decided that I wanted to temporary look at my old code. So I reverted back by using `git revert 845f8d5`.

In hindsight, I realized I should have checked out a new branch first. Then I tried to go back by using `git revert 'fad04be`. When I ran `git status` it said something like `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.`

So next I tried to `git pull` from the remote repository to revert my current code back, and now I'm all confused.

I just want both my local and remote repository to be on commit `fad04be`. What did I do wrong and what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE: before you follow any of my advice, make a full copy of your directory. That way you can always get back to the current situation**

As ouah mentions indeed, your master should now be exactly what you want it to be, with two extra commits, namely the reverts of 845f8d5 and fad04be.

You can do 2 things now. If you didn't push anything to the remote yet, you can put the master pointer back to fad04be by

```
git reset --HARD fad04be
```

Alternatively if you already pushed something to the remote or someone else, you can revert the reverts. If you do a git log, you will see the two most recent commits being the reverts of 845f8d5 and fad04be. You can revert those reverts, by doing

```
git revert <commit-id-of-revert>
```

Next time you want to see an old revision, indeed use:

```
git checkout <revision-id>
```

Don't forget to do a

```
git checkout master
```

when you're done. If you change and commit stuff without doing this, your commits will go somewhere but not in the master branch (git will complain about being in a detached head state, but this warning is easy to miss -- trust me, I've been there :))

Too see an old revision, there is no need to create another branch first.

Comment: +1 - I'd almost finished typing out your paragraph, after being in an almost identical situation to hobbes3. Having a backup *before* running `git reset` will save you a world of hurt if you mess it up.

Comment: Now my `git status` says `# On branch master # Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forward`. I also can't `git push origin master` because it says `To git@bitbucket.org:blahblahblah/something.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:blahblahblah/something.git'`. I am so confused. I need to reread the git tutorial lol.

Comment: It won't let you push because there are other commits on remote that are not on local (that is what the  Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits means). So you first have to do a `git pull --rebase`, and then do your push. Git is extremely powerful, but that also results in the steep learning curve. Don't worry, I think it took most of us a while to get the hang of it!

Comment: Thanks! You have solved my problem for now. Now I gotta hit more tutorials and guides and learn this so I understand it by heart :-).

Comment: Yes, as I said it takes a while to actually understand how git works, but the payoffs are well worth it!

Answer (score 1):

A git revert is actually a commit that just undoes the prior commit. I take it the pull didn't do anything? You should only need to push the revert.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git checkout <commit-id>` to take a quick look to a commit. `git revert <commit-id>` will revert the single commit `<commit-id>` by adding a new commit.